# Spinejs routing not saving state

Tags: coffeescript, history, spine.js

I'm trying to get states into my spine application. On click, an item is added to a list. An url is then created and navigated to, and then the list get's rendered. However, when I use the browsers "back" functionality, the list doesn't change back to the previous state. How to get this to work?

This is the relevant code, I left out what seemed irrelevant, but if more is required I'll provided it.

```
class App extends Spine.Controller  
  constructor: ->
    super
    @products = new Products
    @filters = new Filters

    Filter.bind 'filterAdded', => @navigateAfterFilterChange()
    Filter.bind 'filterRemoved', => @navigateAfterFilterChange()

    Spine.Route.setup( history: false )

  renderAll: ->
    @products.render()
    @filters.render()

  navigateAfterFilterChange: ->
    Spine.Route.navigate( encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( _.map( Filter.active_filters, ( filter ) -> { t: filters.type, v: filters.value } ) ) ) )



class Filter extends Spine.Model
  listen: => #This is used to make the right list item listen to a click event
    $("'a[data-cid=\"#{ @id }\"]'").one 'click', @triggerFilter

  triggerFilter: (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    filter = Filter.find( $( e.currentTarget ).attr( 'data-cid' ) )
    if @active
      @active = false
      Filter.active_filters =  _.reject Filter.active_filters, (x) -> ( x.type is filter.type and x.value is filter.value )
      @save()
      Filter.trigger 'filterRemoved', @
    else
      @active = true
      Filter.active_filters.push filter
      @save()
      Filter.trigger 'filterAdded', @



class Filters extends Spine.Controller
  constructor: ->
    super
    @utils = new GeneralScripts
    @createFilters()
    @listenForTypeActivation()
    @routes
      "": ( params ) ->
        @render()
      "*glob": ( params ) ->
        @render()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but looks like you may need to send params with render()

```
class Filters extends Spine.Controller
  constructor: ->
    super
    @utils = new GeneralScripts
    @createFilters()
    @listenForTypeActivation()
    @routes
      "": ( params ) ->
        @render(params)
      "*glob": ( params ) ->
        @render(params)
```

you would also need to handle params in the render method of course